# Output string contents as HTML markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

Background info: The website can have "widgets" and the mark-up code for them is stored in a database. Starts and ends with the List Item (li) tag.

My controller sends a List listOfWidgets to the view. The view will then loop through that list and can access the mark-up code through a string from the Widget class (listOfWidgets[i].markup)

How can I get my view to put the string markup as actual markup and not display as text? Is there some kind of HTML helper that will do that? For example (I know this is completely wrong, but for example's sake)

@Html.PrintMarkup(listOfWidgets[i].markup)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:
@Html.Raw(listOfWidgets[i].markup)